# Create a global props file with React

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am creating my components, for example here is a div with several texts that are dispatched to the component.

What I would like to do is to make a global configuration file where I would have to modify all the values in one place, for example for this component :

In my component I get `"title"` with `{title},` which I define in my parent component by `title="title"`, and I would like to replace the `"title"` by a variable written in a file like config.js

```
 <Itv titre="titre"
            texte1="texte1"
            texte2="texte2"
            texte3="texte3"
            multi1="multi1"
            multi2="multi2"
            multitre1="titre"
            multitre2="titre"
            multitexte1="texte"
            multitexte2="texte"
            texteimage="texte"
            lien="/amd.jpg"
          />




title = 'title'
```

If someone can help me, thank you

Comment: One solution is to create a React Context, that means all children will have access to the props of the parent, without having to pass them along through every child: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the title value based on the variable, you can do this. In this example, you're associating the value of title to the variable. Upon changing the variable, the `Itv` will update the value of title with the value of the variable.

config.js

```
export const title_var = "title"
```

Itv_file.js

```
import { title_var } from "./config"

<Itv title={title_var} // <- Replace all values similarly to this
            texte1="texte1"
            texte2="texte2"
            texte3="texte3"
            multi1="multi1"
            multi2="multi2"
            multitre1="titre"
            multitre2="titre"
            multitexte1="texte"
            multitexte2="texte"
            texteimage="texte"
            lien="/amd.jpg"
          />
```